# Is there anyway to drag and drop files from browser (angular app) to outlook as an attachment

Tags: javascript, angular, outlook

Requirement:
I have button which downloads as blob (GET API) in the angular app on click.

And I want that button/ or a new link or any other html elememts be able to be dragged from the web app (browser) and dropped in outlook which will result as an attachment in the email
 I don't want the URL to be dragged to outlook.

Is this feature possible.

Browser:chrome

Thanks in advance!
Cheers

Comment: download the blob as file then drag& drop ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there are any "out-of-the-box" solutions for you, but I found the following which should help point you in the right direction:

https://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/gmail-dragout